# Unity change RegisterType for controller (two contexts)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2

I've got problem with switch register DI types.
I try with that but it dont work :/

```
public FirstController([Dependency("GlobalContext")] IUnitOfWorkAsync context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public SecondController(IUnitOfWorkAsync context)
{
    _context = context;
}

container.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, GlobalDataContext>("GlobalContext");
container.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, TenantDataContext>();
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

public UnitOfWork(IDataContextAsync dataContext)
{
    _dataContext = dataContext;
    _repositories = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
}
```

It's possible to do something like that or I must do DI for path from IUnitOfWorkAsync to IDataContextAsync?

I just wanna to tell controller to use that one DI type.

On stackoverflow i find similar question [With Unity how do I inject a named dependency into a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046779/with-unity-how-do-i-inject-a-named-dependency-into-a-constructor)
But it's not the same, I need to create instance of IUnitOfWorkAsync with TenantDataContext in Controller not same class(in my problem TenantDataContext).

Comment: possible duplicate of [With Unity how do I inject a named dependency into a constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046779/with-unity-how-do-i-inject-a-named-dependency-into-a-constructor)

Comment: I try to do that but I can't :/

Comment: The root cause here is that you violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). You are using two different contexts with different data models. Swapping the implementations will break your application (which means you're violating LSP). You should give each context each own interface and this solves the problem completely. It's irrelevant that those two interfaces seem to have the same method signatures; their contract is very different.

Comment: I've got two Api's, and wanna to share "dictionaries" entities between those context's. GlobalContext will be stable and TenantContext have conString provider for our clients. I try o figgure out how I can do it better but for the moment I stay with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution for that problem, and it is similar to suggested question but what I need to do more is to add one more step with dependency.

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, TenantDataContext>("TenantContext", new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>("UnitOfWork", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDataContextAsync>("TenantContext")));
```

And in controller like in first post I use attr Dependency but with another string ["UnitOfWork"]